# Requests return decoded text

Tags: python, json, request

I am super new in python web scraping and i need your help. I am trying to scrape live odds from a bet site using the request.get method. My code so far is this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import brotli
import json

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.goalbetint.com/login/livebet/index.php',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36',
}

params = (
    ('a', 'live'),
    ('eid', '02H43X41251964'),
    ('dt', 's'),
    ('lang', 'GR'),
    ('r', '897947'),
    ('lot', '211'),
    ('dtp', 'jsonp'),
    ('callback', 'jQuery331043529761295563874_1554465530923'),
    ('_', '1554465530948'),
)


r1 = requests.get('https://livedata4.goalbetservices.com:5443/LB_RemoteLiveFeeders/RemoteLiveBet3XML.HTML5.php', headers=headers, params=params)
```

A part of r1.text is this:

```
GameIsVisible":"1","CP":"9","Columns":"0","Mainbet":"0","UsePlayerNames":"0","NEN":"Goal\\/No goal"},"R":[{"attr":{"RID":"02H43X41251964G30-goal","RV":"1","N":"Goal","O0":"4.00","NEN":"Goal"}},{"attr":{"RID":"02H43X41251964G30-nogoal","RV":"1","N":"No Goal","O0":"1.22","NEN":"No Goal"}}]},{"attr":{"GameID":"02H43X41251964G1108","N":"Goal\\/No goal \\u03b4\\u03b5\\u03cd\\u03c4\\u03b5\\u03c1\\u03bf\\u03c5 \\u03b7\\u03bc\\u03b9\\u03c7\\u03c1\\u03cc\\u03bd\\u03bf
```

Which is ok because I get the odd somewhere ""1.22"" but I want the part `\\u03b4\\u03b5\\u03cd\\u03c4\\u03b5\\u03c1\\u03bf\\u03c5 \\u03b7\\u03bc\\u03b9\\u03c7\\u03c1\\u03cc\\u03bd\\u03bf`

to be decoded or something like this. This part probably refers to a text. How can I decode and/or store the response in dictionary?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be decoded: it is in UTF-8 which is the Python default. Just print out the value. The reason you are seeing backslashes is that you are printing out raw data structures.

For example:

```
>>> a = """Goal\/No goal \u03b4\u03b5\u03cd\u03c4\u03b5\u03c1\u03bf\u03c5 \u03b7\u03bc\u03b9\u03c7\u03c1\u03cc\u03bd\u03bf"""
>>> a
'Goal\\/No goal δεύτερου ημιχρόνο'
```

Comment: Thank you! I observe that my response looks alike to a dictionary. Can I store it that way? In another bet site I used:

a3=json.loads(response.text)

and then a3 is a dictionary but when I try the same thing to this case i get an error:

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Comment: Your question does not present enough of `r1` to suggest why you getting JSON decode errors. But normally the Expecting value error tells you the line, the column and the character offset in your string that it doesn't like.